# Gitlab CI notifications for scheduled pipeline failures

Tags: gitlab-ci

My requirement is to send notification on consecutive build failures.

I don’t want to send notifications for pipeline status change. If the pipeline fails say consecutive 5 times, notify by mail. Any thoughts.

Also is it possible to set/unset or increment pipeline scheduled variables inside gitlab-ci.yml file.